# How to join two elements by dragging the arrow in Ajax Trueclient Protocol

Tags: ajax, loadrunner

I am working for campaigns and in that I need to merge two selection boxes by dragging to Merge element. Please see image for further clarification.

[image]

Comment: Would this be easier as a pure HTTP protocol virtual user where you are then just concerned with the request instead of the GUI actions?

Comment: application is not static it will change every 15 days so using Ajax true client protocol. And the management team is concerned with both GUI and request. Any ways to join these boxes?

Comment: Measure your GUI in your single user functional testing. Using all Truclient will still not help you understand the weight of your GUI and its impact on response time.  Look at the developer tools which can measure the cost of every single action inside the browser.  Deploy a handful of GUI/Truclient virtual users paired with the HTTP users to measure the delta between Login_HTTP and Login_GUI|TruClient on reference Browsers and hardware.